# How to remove "email" and "url" fields in WordPress comment form?

Tags: php, wordpress, comments

How can I remove Email and Website fields in "Leave a Reply" form in WordPress?

Like this : [URL removed - malware link]

I only want to see **`Name (leave blank for Anonymous)`** and the comment field.

I'm using WordPress 3.2.1 and using the default WordPress comments.

`public_html/wp-includes/comment.php`

and

`public_html/wp-includes/comment-template.php`

I've removed this code from comment-template.php:

```
'email'  => '<p class="comment-form-email"><label for="email">' . __( 'Email' ) . '</label> ' . ( $req ? '<span class="required">*</span>' : '' ) .
                    '<input id="email" name="email" type="text" value="' . esc_attr(  $commenter['comment_author_email'] ) . '" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' /></p>',
        'url'    => '<p class="comment-form-url"><label for="url">' . __( 'Website' ) . '</label>' .
                    '<input id="url" name="url" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author_url'] ) . '" size="30" /></p>',
```

But this is not working. I think removing only this code is not enough!

Now what do I do?

Comment: http://techhacking.com/2011/02/04/wordpress-how-to-remove-the-website-field-from-the-comment-form/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Create this plugin using notepad application from windows and remember to save the file with a .php extension Eg : removeurl.php
2. Copy and paste the below code in the file created in step 1

   ```
   <?php
   /*
   Plugin Name: Remove Website Field
   Description: Removes the website field from the comments form
   */
   add_filter('comment_form_default_fields', 'url_filtered');
   function url_filtered($fields)
   {
     if(isset($fields['url']))
      unset($fields['url']);
     return $fields;
   }

   ?>
   ```

Plugin Credit goes to TechHacking.com

1. Save your changes and upload it via FTP or through your web hosts file manager to the /wp-content/plugins/ directory
2. Go plugins menu option in your wordpress admin area and activate the plugin.  With this simple hack you will be to remove the website field from the comment form.

**If  in any case the plugin does not work or the function does not work you can also use this method, I used this method in lot of my customization work and its proved to be very effect without any problem.
To do so open your theme main css (Style Sheet) copy and paste below code**

```
#commentform #url, #commentform #url +label {display:none;}
```

source : http://www.shariff.org/remove-website-field-comment-form.html

Answer (score 3):

since the question specified talks about Email and Website Field, i modified @king Tohi's answer:

```
    <?php
/*
Plugin Name: Remove Website and Email Field
Description: Removes the website field and email Field from the comments form
*/
add_filter('comment_form_default_fields', 'url_filtered');
function url_filtered($fields)
{
  if(isset($fields['url']))
   unset($fields['url']);
  return $fields;
}

add_filter('comment_form_default_fields', 'email_filtered');
function email_filtered($fields)
{
  if(isset($fields['email']))
   unset($fields['email']);
  return $fields;
}

?>
```

Hope this saves a soul...

EDIT:

In my case after disabling the field, the email field was compulsory so i had to disable it

`settings > discussion >`unselect`Comment author must fill out name and email`

Answer (score 0):

Go to admin

> > dashboard >> Settings >> Discussions

Here you have to Uncheck "Comment author must fill name and email" and all set.

try it :)

Comment: you want to validate content of comment like comment should not have email / website URL ?